# Поиск по бинам, не выводит значение столбца найденного бина

Tags: php, redbeanphp

Вместо найденного столбца выводит `null`. Не понимаю в чем проблема?
Ведь если сделать `var_dump($task_1)`, то бин отображается.

Код:

```
list($table, $tasks)  = R::dispenseAll( 'tables,task' );//для двух таблиц
$id= $_SESSION["id"];
$rows=R::findAll('tables','`id_user`=?',array($id)); //находит в таблице записи текущего пользователя
for($i=1;$i<count($rows)+1;$i++)
  {
    $table2=$rows[$i]->id_table; 
    $task_1=R::find('tasks','id_tables=?',array($table2));//находит в другой таблице записи по нужной таблице
    var_dump($task_1->text);//здесь должно выводить значение найденного столбца
    /*....*/
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что я пытаюсь вывести из массива данных конкретное свойство. Нужно использовать `foreach`